# "Obtenir l'argent" ou "gagner l'argent"

Tags: choix-de-mot

Je voulais savoir si on dit "obtenir l'argent" ou "gagner l'argent" et lequel est le plus utilisé.

Je suis nouveau dans le stackexchange francais ; puis-je écrire en anglais ?

Comment: Pas de problème, vous pouvez poser les questions en français ou en anglais.  L'usage est alors que les réponses seront dans la même langue que la question. .

Comment: Why did you accept LPH's response?

Comment: Whether one phrase is better or not, is more used or not primarily depends about what you want to express. You should edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: @jlliagre I want to say ' I want a job in order to make money'. Anyways I got an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans la plupart des contextes, on dira "gagner de l'argent", avec un partitif "de", si on parle d'argent en général,  sans préciser de quel argent on parle.

Ex: grâce à ce nouveau contrat, je gagne enfin de l'argent

Il a un bon travail, il gagne beaucoup d'argent

Si on parle d'une somme précise d'argent, on peut dire "gagner l'argent ", en précisant de quel argent il s'agit.

Ex: il a dépensé l'argent qu'il avait gagné au poker

Comment: L'argent est un moyen d'échange numéraire : *de* + *le* est certes indéfini mais pas indénombrable ou inquantifiable (en fait, c'est même tout l'opposé). Par conséquent, *de l'* n'est pas un article partitif. En poursuivant l'analyse, on s'aperçoit que votre point de vue est biaisé.

Comment: Si "de l'" n'est pas un article partitif, qu'est-ce ? En quoi est-ce différent de par exemple "de l'eau" ou " de l'or" ? L'argent est quantifiable en tant que monnaie, mais ce n'est alors plus le même mot qu'on utilisera. On peut pas compter "un argent", "deux argents", "trois argents", c'est donc bien un nom indénombrable. On peut compter évidemment "un euro, deux euros", mais ce n'est plus le vocable "de l'argent :. J'avoue ne pas comprendre votre commentaire.

Comment: https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-101107.php

Comment: L'argent représente un concept mais l'expression *gagner de l'argent* signifie en général *avoir de la monnaie*. Lorsqu'on dit *On a gagné de l'argent*, on peut se poser judicieusement la question *Combien avez-vous gagné ?*

Comment: Qu'est-ce que c'est ? Un article élidé précédé d'une préposition.

Comment: ... et cela correspond exactement à la définition d'un article partitif. Cf wikipedia p.ex. "Du point de vue morphologique, l'article partitif singulier est le même que l'article défini singulier précédé de la préposition « de "

Comment: Je me permets de renvoyer à la définition très claire de l'article partitif du Robert. Dans les exemples d'usage de partitifs, on retrouve texto "de l'argent": https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/articles-partitifs *Prends de l'argent dans le tiroir.*

Comment: La définition du Robert est erronée dans ce cas. À comparer avec celle plus sensée de l'[Académie](http://academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#64_strong-em-partitif-et-dterminant-em-strong) : *En français, on utilise l’article partitif (du, de la, des) devant un nom désignant un tout qu’on ne peut dénombrer **ou qu’on renonce à dénombrer**, pour dire qu’on prélève une quantité indéterminée de ce tout : manger du chocolat, de la tarte, des épinards.*

Comment: *Argent* dans ce sens colle parfaitement: on renonce à dénombrer *de l'argent*. C'est exactement la même chose que *de la colle, de l'eau,  du papier*, etc. Let's agree to disagree

Comment: Je suis d'accord sauf que la définition du Robert est vraiment contradictoire (d'où la contradiction dans votre propos).

Comment: Quoi qu'il en soit, je vous invite à lire ce [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43485/obtenir-largent-ou-gagner-largent#comment88317_43485) de jlliagre.

Answer (score 2):

- ***Gagner*** (win, make, earn) is the opposite of *perdre* (lose) or *dépenser* (spent)
- ***Argent*** means either *money* or *silver*, depending on the context
- ***Obtenir*** (obtain, get) is the opposite of *se voir refuser* (to be denied sth).

***Gagner l'argent*** can thus mean "win the silver medal" if you are talking about an Olympic games sportsperson, or "be the one who earns the household money": *gagner l'argent du ménage*.
If you want to translate "to make money", you would say instead *gagner **de** l'argent*, as [Greg rightly wrote](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43492/1109) (+1).

With ***obtenir***, the partitive *de* is also usually expected. Unlike *gagner*, ***obtenir*** means there was some sort of negotiation or maybe dispute and finally, the person asking for it got money.

***Obtenir de l'argent*** is a single event, unlike ***gagner de l'argent*** which can be a repetitive one.

Comment: We could also add that *gagner de l'argent* implies the money was earned by as result of one's professionnal activities OR as a gain in a game. If one gets some money outside of those activities, the less specific *recevoir* will fit. Ex: *j'ai reçu de l'argent pour mon anniversaire*.

Comment: @Greg Indeed, that can be *j'ai trouvé de l'argent* too.

Answer (score 0):

L'expression **Gagner l'argent** est généralement utilisée quand on parle d'un afflux monétaire resultant d'un travail, contrat, ..., en somme de l'argent résultant d'un effort physique ou autre.

**Obtenir l'argent** qui peut être utilisé comme synonyme de *gagner l'argent* est plus utilisé quand on l'obtient sans effort comme gagner dans un jeux de chance, d'une source illégale, l'obtenir en héritage ....

Answer (score -1):

Il n'y a pas à proprement parler de verbe qui soit plus *utile* que l'autre dans cette comparaison des verbes « gagner » et « obtenir ». Lorsque vous avez besoin du concept qui correspond à « obtenir » il n'y a pratiquement aucune chance de pouvoir utiliser « gagner » à sa place en ajoutant des modifications. Vice versa, la possibilité existe mais elle n'est pas réaliste. Remarquons, dans le but de vérifier cela, que « gagner »  définit une sous-classe de « obtenir » ; dans les termes de la linguistique on dit que « obtenir » est un *hyperonyme* de « gagner » ([hyperonymie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperonymie)) ou en terme de  la relation converse que « gagner » est un *hyponyme* de « obtenir »  ([hyponymie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymie)) ; on voit cela d'après la définition lexicale de « gagner », qui est « **obtenir** de l'argent/une somme/salaire/etc. par le moyen d'un échange pour du travail, des produits, des services, etc. ».
On peut cependant parler d'utilité dans le sens de quel verbe est le plus souvent mis à contribution dans le parler et dans l'écrit.

Dans l'écrit le verbe "obtenir" apparait le plus souvent ; malgré l'apparente prédominance dans la vie humaine du concept énoncé par « gagner », c'est « [obtenir](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gagner%2Cobtenir&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgagner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobtenir%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgagner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobtenir%3B%2Cc0) » qui arrive en tête. On pourrait considérer cela comme normal ou logique puisque « obtenir »  « couvre » « gagner » (hyperonymie) mais il n'existe pas de telle loi : par exemple « primate » est un hyperonyme de « être humain »  mais la fréquence d'occurrence du premier est largement inférieure à celle du second (Si ce n'est pas évident cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=primate%2C%C3%AAtre+humain&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprimate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20humain%3B%2Cc0) devrait éliminer tout doute.).
La situation est renversée et l'écart se creuse lorsqu'on ajoute « [de l'argent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gagner+de+l%27argent%2Cobtenir+de+l%27argent&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgagner%20de%20l%27%20argent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobtenir%20de%20l%27%20argent%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgagner%20de%20l%27%20argent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobtenir%20de%20l%27%20argent%3B%2Cc0) » comme complément de ces verbes ; cela se comprend en cela que    le concept de l'obtention d'argent est central dans ce plus important des soucis que tout le monde a, ce soucis étant  de se garantir une existence confortable.
C'est ce contexte universel qui fait que l'on utilise énormément « gagner » ; on l'utilise énormément parce que l'idée d'échange est capitale. On n'a pas cette idée avec « obtenir ».  Il y a des contexte où, bien sûr, c'est « obtenir » qui sera en matière d'argent le seul terme utilisable.

- Il **gagne** un bon salaire  et **obtient** des primes assez souvent. (*Noter que l'on dit plutôt « obtenir » que « gagner » une prime ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gagn%C3%A9+une+prime%2Cobtenu+une+prime&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgagn%C3%A9%20une%20prime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobtenu%20une%20prime%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgagn%C3%A9%20une%20prime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobtenu%20une%20prime%3B%2Cc0)).*)
- Cet employé **a obtenu** un bon salaire de son patron parce qu'il a su lui démontrer une aptitude spéciale à résoudre des problèmes peu communs. (*Il s'agit d'une entente entre deux personnes ou bien du résultat d'une décision sans discussion par
  une seule personne (le patron).*)
- Elle **a obtenu** de l'argent de son patron sur la base d'un remboursement par retenue régulière sur son salaire. (*Il est question d'un prêt et « gagner » ne convient pas du tout.*)
- Elle **obtient** régulièrement de l'argent de sa mère ; il lui suffit pour cela de lui demander. (*Il n'y a aucune idée d'échange dans le présent contexte et « gagner » ne peut pas convenir.*)

#### *Complément suite à des commentaires*

La définition du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gagner) ne rend pas explicite la notion d'effort.

> I. − Acquérir (quelque chose).
> A. − [Le suj. désigne une pers.] Acquérir (un profit matériel, particulièrement de l'argent).
>
> 1. [Par son travail ou une quelconque activité]
> 2. [Par le jeu, un hasard favorable]

Cependant, une considération des cas montre que le gain sans effort n'est qu'exceptionnel. La partie « 2 » de la définition ne compte que pour une proportion négligeable des cas de gain d'argent dans lesquels « gagner » est idiomatique.

Lorsqu'on utilise « gagner » il existe presque toujours un contexte où la personne qui « gagne » doit contribuer de sa personne. Même en parlant par exemple d'un gros fabriquant qui gagne énormément d'argent, le gain n'est pas sans effort, ou sans responsabilités et soucis, ce qui est équivalent à un effort. De nos jours, où on ne parle plus trop de prostituées et où nous tendons à référer  à une catégorie du monde du travail, celles des travailleurs du sexe, l'idée de base nouvelle que ces personnes font un effort est indiscutable ; on doit selon le principe de la reconnaissance de leur activité comme étant une activité légitime, dire qu'elles gagnent leur argent.
Il y a quelques exceptions, comme lorsque l'on parle des gain qui résultent du jeu : course de chevaux, loterie nationale, jeux de carte, jeux d'échec, jeux sportifs, etc. Dans cette catégorie de gains, où on peut difficilement parler d'un effort lorsqu'il s'agit  de jeux de pur hasard on utilise « gagner ».

- Il a gagné gros au loto et c'est pour ça qu'il a déménagé.
- L'argent que vous gagnez au tiercé n'est pas imposable à l'impôt sur le revenu.

On peut cependant se demander si les risques que constituent les mises nécessaires pour jouer ne constituent pas un effort.

Lorsqu'on parle des jeux où les capacités mentales (et sans discussion possible les capacités physiques) de la personne qui gagne de l'argent sont la base de son gain on utilise aussi « gagner » mais je pense qu'on doit indiscutablement considérer qu'un effort est fourni par les gens qui gagnent de l'argent dans ces jeux.

À mon avis les cas de gain sans effort où « gagner » est idiomatique sont très exceptionnels dans ce monde.

Comment: Est-ce-que "gagner" n'utilise pas lorsque il n'y a pas d'effort impliqué? Je suis desollé pour mes francais.

Comment: *Gagner de l'argent* n'implique pas un effort: on peut dire par exemple "c'est de l'argent facilement gagné".

Comment: @Greg Ces cas de gains sans trop d'effort sont plutôt rares mais il me semble qu'il y a presque toujours une contribution personnelle à la base et je me demande si on ne doit pas considérer cela comme équivalent a à un effort. Il me semble qu'une personne qui contribue par exemple une  somme (grosse ou petite) à une œuvre de charité, fait un effort ; la contribuer à une entreprise dans une opération boursière ne constitue pas un effort aussi ?

Comment: @user716881 J'ai ajouté un complément à ma réponse.

Comment: Bon courage à ceux qui adhèrent à de telles inepties !